# TikZ: `behind path` Key Inoperative With Angles Library

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic, tikz-angles, layers

I am using the `angles` library to label angles in my diagrams. I'm noticing, however, that the arc created by the `angles` package rests on a layer above the rest of the diagram by default, i.e., the following MWE produces the picture below it and to the left.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [red,thick]
        (0,0) coordinate (B) --
        (2,0) coordinate (A) --
        (2,1.2) coordinate (C) pic[pic text={$\theta$},draw,black,ultra thick,angle radius=8mm,angle eccentricity=1.2]{angle} --
        cycle
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image] [image]

I would like to produce a picture where the arc lies on a lower layer (as in the picture above and to the right). As I understand it, this should be possible by adding the `behind path` key to the optional parameters describing the `pic` (the `behind path` key *does* work on my computer with both nodes and pics outside of the `angles` library, so I'm pretty sure it's just a problem with `angles`). However, this has no effect. What's up with this behavior, and **what modification to the optional parameters describing the `pic` will produce the intended result?**

Note that the following MWE produces the desired result (the picture above and to the right) using the `backgrounds` library and a `scope`. I am asking, though, how to avoid using this construct (or, I suppose, drawing a second red triangle on top of the original, or any other forced construct).

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,backgrounds}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [red,thick]
        (0,0) coordinate (B) --
        (2,0) coordinate (A) --
        (2,1.2) coordinate (C) --
        cycle
    ;
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
        \pic[pic text={$\theta$},draw,ultra thick,angle radius=8mm,angle eccentricity=1.2]{angle};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, page 568 of the 3.1.5b manual states that drawings are made in front of the path. I quote `Concerning the sector that makes up the drawing of the angle, the angular part of this sector is drawn in front of the path if the draw option is given to the pic, while filled sector is drawn behind the pic, provided an option like fill or shade is passed to the pic.`

Comment: from the manual version 3.1.5b, page 225: `Note that behind path only applies to the current path; not to the current scope or picture.` So the problem is the red triangle drawn before is NOT the current path when you draw the angle symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `angles` library explicitly puts some part of the code in the background and some other the foreground. You could write your own pic based on the code:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,backgrounds}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  pics/backangle/.style = {
    setup code  = \tikz@lib@angle@parse#1\pgf@stop,
    background code = \tikz@lib@angle@background#1\pgf@stop\tikz@lib@angle@foreground#1\pgf@stop,
    %foreground code = \tikz@lib@angle@foreground#1\pgf@stop,
  },
  pics/right backangle/.style = {
    setup code  = \tikz@lib@angle@parse#1\pgf@stop,
    background code = \tikz@lib@rightangle@background#1\pgf@stop\tikz@lib@rightangle@foreground#1\pgf@stop,
    %foreground code = \tikz@lib@rightangle@foreground#1\pgf@stop,
  },
  pics/backangle/.default=A--B--C,
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [red,thick]
        (0,0) coordinate (B) --
        (2,0) coordinate (A) --
        (2,1.2) coordinate (C) pic[pic text={$\theta$},draw,black,ultra thick,angle radius=8mm,angle eccentricity=1.2,]{backangle} --
        cycle
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]